# Take advantage of the DI within a factory class

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Suppose I have a group of classes that should be instantiated by a factory. This factory has to inject a parameter to the instantiated class.

```php
<?php
class ClassA
{
    public function __constructor(
        \My\Logger $logger,
        \Dependency\For\ClassA $dependencyA2,
        \One\More\Dependency\For\ClassA $dependencyA3,
        ...
        string $parameterInjectedByTheFactory

    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->dependencyA2 = $dependencyA2;
        ...
        $this->parameterInjectedByTheFactory = $parameterInjectedByTheFactory;
    }
}
```

and

```php
<?php
class ClassB
{
    public function __constructor(
        \My\Logger $logger,
        \Dependency\For\ClassB $dependencyB2,
        \One\More\Dependency\For\ClassB $dependencyB3,
        ...
        string $parameterInjectedByTheFactory
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->dependencyB2 = $dependencyB2;
        ...
        $this->parameterInjectedByTheFactory = $parameterInjectedByTheFactory;
    }
}
```

I feel the following class is wrong. It shouldn't know about the particular dependencies for `ClassA` and `ClassB`, isn't it?

```php
class Factory
{
    public function __constructor(
        \My\Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function make($class, $myParameter)
    {
        switch($class)
        {
            case 'ClassA':
                return new $class(
                    $this->logger,
                    new \Dependency\For\ClassA,
                    ...
                    $myParameter
                )            
            case 'ClassB':
                return new $class(
                    $this->logger,
                    new \Dependency\For\ClassB,
                    ...
                    $myParameter
                )
        }
    }
}
```

I want to take advantage of the DI autowiring to instantiate classA and classB, but is a bad practice to inject the container in a factory.

A more realistic example. I have an `EndpointManager` with a method `get($endpointCode)` that looks for $endpointCode in an array. This array entry has the information to build the endpoint:

```php
<?php
[
    'endpoint1' => [
        'class' => '\My\Class\For\Dealing\With\MySQL',
        'connectionData' => 'mysql:user@localhost',
    ],

    'endpoint2' => [
        'class' => '\My\Class\For\Dealing\With\REST',
        'connectionData' => [
            'url': 'https://localhost/api/rest/',
            ...
        ],
    ],
]
```

The `EndpointManager` has to instantiate an object of the class defined in the `'class'` entry and pass to it the `connectionData`. But the constructors for `\My\Class\For\Dealing\With\MySQL` and `\My\Class\For\Dealing\With\REST` are heterogeneus, each of them with their own potentially large set of dependencies. Is there a way to leverage the DI to instantiate these objects.

What's the best approach for this situation?

Comment: you've mentioned that "...but is a bad practice to inject the container in a factory." Well, not really so. Factories are not supposed to be elements of application code. I would suggest reading [this (last three paragraphs are the most important regarding your question)](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) and [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) to get more info on the topic.

Comment: @xmike Good response and very interesting links. You opened my eyes. I'll inject the container just to deal with those objects creation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate the creation of concrete class to anonymous function, for example

```
<?php

$dependencyManager>add('endpoint1', function ($di) {
     return new \My\Class\For\Dealing\With\MySQL('mysql:user@localhost', .., ...);
});

$dependencyManager>add('endpoint2', function ($di) {
     return new \My\Class\For\Dealing\With\REST('https://localhost/api/rest/', .., ..., ...);
});
```

To get the instance class:

```
<?php

$endpoint1Instance = $dependencyManager->get('endpoint1');
$endpoint2Instance = $dependencyManager->get('endpoint2');
```

where `add()` and `get()` methods may be declared like below:

```
<?php

class DependencyManager 
{
    private $dependencies = [];
    ...

    public function add($key, callable $factory)
    {
          $this->dependencies[$key]['instance'] = null;
          $this->dependencies[$key]['factory'] = $factory;
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
       if (isset($this->dependencies[$key]) {               
           $instance = $this->dependencies[$key]['instance'];
           if (is_null($instance)) {
               $instance = $this->dependencies[$key]['factory']($this);
               $this->dependencies[$key]['instance'] = $instance;
           }
           return  $instance;
       } else {
          throw new Exception('not found');
       }    
    }
    ...
}
```

You may want to look at existing dependency manager implementation, for example [Pimple](https://pimple.symfony.com/).

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your response. I know about Pimple. But I'm using PHP-DI. But my question was about to get rid of the manual instantiation (return new \My\Class\For\Dealing\With\MySQL('mysql:user@localhost', .., ...);) and take advantage of the autowiring feature of PHP-DI to deal with the constructor arguments.